# Site is not loading since early today

Tags: domain-name-system, centos6, loading

Since early this morning I cannot access my website http://naruto-tv.tv and also using putty I couldn't access the server.  However I have other accounts on the server and I can access these websites and they are loading fine.

The OS is CentOS6.

My IP is not blocked because the server is down for all other people and I didn't change the password.

I cannot access the server using putty and FileZilla, however I could access the root using the following method:

1. I opened a connection to another remote server using PuTTY
2. sftp to access the naruto-tv.tv server

I downloaded the error log and nothing in it.  The website is using wordpress.

I did try to check the DNS and there seems to be issues which sadly I don't understand.

The webhosting doesn't support software issues and they couldn't access the server too.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The website http://naruto-tv.tv opens for me without problems.

Comment: thanks. I tested it on 3 servers in europe. I can see it working on sites like http://www.justdownforme.com/ which gave an error all the time... really irritating not to know what is happening .-(

Comment: Those DNS issues you don't understand - figure them out, or seek advise.  You won't get far telling anyone there are "issues" but not saying what they are.

Answer (score 1):

One of your authoritative name servers is not responding:

The working one:

```
> dig @ns1.alma3aref.com naruto-tv.tv

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @ns1.alma3aref.com naruto-tv.tv
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51207
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;naruto-tv.tv.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
naruto-tv.tv.       14400   IN  A   46.19.33.207

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
naruto-tv.tv.       86400   IN  NS  ns2.alma3aref.com.
naruto-tv.tv.       86400   IN  NS  ns1.alma3aref.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.alma3aref.com.  14400   IN  A   46.19.33.207
ns2.alma3aref.com.  14400   IN  A   46.19.34.28

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 46.19.33.207#53(46.19.33.207)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 16 15:16:19 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

And the broken one:

```
> dig @ns2.alma3aref.com naruto-tv.tv

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @ns2.alma3aref.com naruto-tv.tv
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This will cause a random selection of roughly half your visitors to be unable to resolve the IP address for your site.

My guess is that `bind` is not running on your **other** server.

There are some [other problems with your DNS](http://intodns.com/naruto-tv.tv).  No glue for your second authoritative nameserver is a problem.  You will need to go to where you registered the domain to fix this.